# How can I reset value of a date picker when using MatDateRangeSelectionStrategy?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using angular material's date picker and came accross [this example](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#customizing-the-date-selection-logic)

I've implemented the example with my own logic and everything worked great except the date is returned from the `MatDateRangeSelectionStrategy` class which is an injection token I guess (don't really know how that works) and this class only contains returns date range based on UI triggered events (The two events are `selectionFinished` and `createPreview`). When a date range is selected I couldn't find a way to reset it programmatically or via the DOM.

I've tried so far:

```
            <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
              <mat-label>Select a start date</mat-label>
              <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="picker">
                <input [value]="newStart"disabled="true" (dateChange)="startNewChanged($event.value)"  matStartDate placeholder="Start date">
                <input [value]="newEnd" disabled="true" matEndDate placeholder="End date">
              </mat-date-range-input>
              <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
              <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
            </mat-form-field>
```

where `newStart` and `newEnd` are dates but this overrides the selected range.
What could I do else?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:
set viewChild to your

```
<mat-date-range-input #dateRangeInput [rangePicker]="picker">
```

TS:

```
@ViewChild('dateRangeInput ') dateRangeInput: MatDateRangePicker<Moment>;
```

Them call this method:

```
this.pickerDR.select(undefined);
```